# jQuery: Changing a function into an IIFE?

Tags: jquery

**Code:**

```
jQuery(function() {
  function addRow(table) {
    jQuery("<tr>", {
      class: "added_row"
    }).appendTo(jQuery("tbody", table));
  }
  function moveColumn(cIndex, table) {
    var head = jQuery("thead th", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    var cell = jQuery("tbody tr:eq(0) td", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    addRow(table);
    head.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(1)", table);
    addRow(table);
    cell.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(2)", table);
  }
  moveColumn(2, jQuery(".list"));
});
```

I've never converted a function to an IIFE before but would this be the correct function once it's converted to an IIFE? :

```
(function ($) {
  function addRow(table) {
    jQuery("<tr>", {
      class: "added_row"
    }).appendTo(jQuery("tbody", table));
  }
  function moveColumn(cIndex, table) {
    var head = jQuery("thead th", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    var cell = jQuery("tbody tr:eq(0) td", table).eq(cIndex).detach();
    addRow(table);
    head.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(1)", table);
    addRow(table);
    cell.appendTo("tbody tr:eq(2)", table);
  }
  moveColumn(2, jQuery(".list"));
})(jQuery);
```

Appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. You can also use `$` instead of `jQuery` inside your IIFE, since you pass the parameter in the function you're creating.

Comment: yes that's an IIFE, but be aware that is not equivalent to using `JQuery(...)`

Comment: I don't see why you need to change this to an IIFE. It's already running immediately, and because it's inside `function(){}` it has a local scope just like an IIFE. It's essentially an IIFE that runs when the DOM is ready rather than immediately.